# SCSS target class before :hover

Tags: css, sass

When I am inside :hover I want to continue adding on previous class using **&**

But when I use & inside :hover - it forms class along with :hover

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu1JH.png)

WHAT I WANT: inside of `:hover { }` I want to continue "the chain" like this, instead of retyping whole class from the beggining

```
&:hover {
  &__accent__product-box { transform: scale(1.1); }
}
```

This results like this when compiled:

[image]

And I want to compile like this:

[image]

Comment: What about `&__accent__product-box {:hover &{}}`?

Comment: &__accent__product-box { :hover &{transform: scale(1.1);} } ? It scales wherever my cursor is on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the ampersand `&` via a variable.

```
.parent {
  $this: &;
  
  &:hover {
    
    #{$this}__variation--active {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```