# SASS with BEM hover state

Tags: css, class, sass, hover, bem

```
    .card {
      &__header {}

      &__title {}

      &__content {}

      &__hasFullImage {

        &:hover {
          &__header {}

          //I want something like this
          .card__header {}

          //and not to type the parent class
        }
      }
    }
```

So Im facing a situation where I'm using BEM with SASS, and for me the whole point of this is I can grab my SCSS file to other project change the name of the parent class to whatever I want and will work. But in this situation on Hover I can't reach the .card__header without using &__header, so If I change the parent class I will need to change the class on hover aswell.
Because the output will be .card__hasFullImage .card__hasFullImage__header and what I want is .card__hasFullImage .card__header.
Is there any way to do this without typing the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.card {
  $this: &;
  
 &__hasFullImage {
   &:hover {
      #{$this}__header {}
    }
}
```

[SCSS target class before :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225811/scss-target-class-before-hover?noredirect=1#comment111802137_63225811) - I had same issue

Comment: copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225880/13808619

Comment: Yes, that's my question I had exact issue before 15mins