# How to extend top-level selector in chain by another class

Tags: css, sass

I have scss difine with this content:

```
.dialog {
  ...
    
  .dialog-content {
    ...
          
    .dialog-content-header {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

This will result into css:

```
...
.dialog .dialog-content .dialog-content-header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I need to find a way how to reach this:

```
...
.dialog.dialog-with-train .dialog-content .dialog-content-header {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The additional .dialog-with-train selector should be added somehow from .dialog-content-header context.
Is it possible something like this?

```
.dialog {
  ...
    
  .dialog-content {
    ...
          
    .dialog-content-header {
      background-color: red;

      @at-root getFirstItem(&).dialog-with-train getItems(&, 2, ?length?) {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The path from .dialog to .dialog-content-header is in my case quite complex and I would like to do the change in some clean way without modyfing and repeating existing code.

Any advice?

EDIT1: looking at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector, is there any way hot to parse+compose the selectors path to required composition?

EDIT2: I found some solution by string subratraction of selector using `@use "sass:string";`. See my accepted answer.

If there will be better or cleaner solution I would like to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCSS target class before :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225811/scss-target-class-before-hover)

Comment: Actually not. The structure is quite complex I mentioned example is not applicable to my usecase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this one works:

```
@use "sass:string";

.dialog {
  $dialog: &;
  ...
    
  .dialog-content {
    ...
          
    .dialog-content-header {
      background-color: red;

      @at-root #{$dialog}.dialog-with-train #{str-slice("#{&}", str-length("#{$dialog}") + 2)} {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How it works?

1. define `$dialog` in the context
2. `@at-root` generates selector from root context
3. `#{$dialog}.dialog-with-train` extends first selector by required class
4. `#{str-slice("#{&}", str-length("#{$dialog}") + 2)}` provides subtraction of current selector and `$dialog` selector

In details how did I perform "subtraction":

1. `str-length("#{$dialog}")` count string length of `$dialog` selector
2. `"#{&}"` gets current context selector as string
3. `#{str-slice("#{&}", str-length("#{$dialog}") + 2)}` gets substring from current selector. First char of subtraction starts 2 chars after `$dialog` selector ends

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your process and use a methodology like [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/).

```
.dialog {
  
  $c: &;

  &-content {
    
    &-header {
    
      background-color: red;
      
      #{$c}--with-train & {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.dialog-content-header {
  background-color: red;
}
.dialog--with-train .dialog-content-header {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: this might work with project which I write from scratch... Actually in my case the "rethink" is not possible. The methodology is given and I cannot change class naming and structure by your proposal. But the idea is interesting